# Paginate Child Pages Content on Parent Page

Tags: pagination, child-pages

I am using the following code to display child page content on it's parent page. The code is working great, but it currently only shows the latest two child page posts, is there any way to display all of them and then add pagination to navigate through them?

```
<?php
    $pages = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=desc');
    $count = 0;
    foreach($pages as $page) {
        $content = $page->post_content;
        if($count >= 2)
            break;
        $count++;
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
        echo "<h2>".$page->post_title."</h2>";
        echo "<p>".$content."</p>";
    }
?>
```

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching I was able to find this post: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-pagination-to-list-of-child-pages

My final code looks like this:

```
<?php
    $ids = array();
    $pages = get_pages("child_of=".$post->ID);
    if ($pages) {
        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            $ids[] = $page->ID;
        }
    }
    $paged = (get_query_var("paged")) ? get_query_var("paged") : 1;
    $args = array(
        "paged" => $paged,
        "post__in" => $ids,
        "posts_per_page" => 2,
        "post_type" => "page"
    );
    query_posts($args);
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <h2>Oh No!!</h2>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo get_next_posts_link(); ?>
<?php echo get_previous_posts_link(); ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I really like this code because it pulls the content using a loop, making it easier to pull the things you want from the page (as well as creating a custom query)...I edited a few lines from the link I found and tried to simplify it as much as possible.

I hope this helps someone else out there, worked like a champ for me!

**Note:** I wanted to display just the child pages and no grand child pages, so if you'd also like to do that add `"parent=".$post->ID` to `line 3` in the code above. *The line will look like: `$pages = get_pages("parent=".$post->ID."&child_of=".$post->ID);`

Thanks,
Josh